# incomplete twitter friend list in python using tweepy

Tags: python-2.7, tweepy

I tried printing my twitter friendlist.I have 112 friends but i am able to print screennames of only 20 friends. Is it because of some API limit/difference between friends and following/conceptual error.This is my  code:

```
import tweepy
import sys
import time
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
data = api.get_user('')

count = 0
for friend in data.friends():
        print 'Friend:'+ friend.screen_name
        count=count+1
        if count%5==0:
            print count
        time.sleep(20)
```

My interpreter is not throwing any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Twitter returns 15 records per call. To get more:

- ask Tweepy for more (`count=100`) -- [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17411503/143880)

or

- use a Cursor to iterate over all the data; see [Tutorial](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/docs/cursor_tutorial.rst)